# Do you know any server file picker/uploader for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I'm building an application which requires the user to pick an image file from the images folder on the server.

What I am looking for is a popup plugin that when clicking the browse button it will show a list of all files in the specified folder and return the filename of the selected file.
Additionally (but not mandatory) I would like if there was an option to upload a file before selection and to display the files as thumbnails.

A very nice example (without image upload though) using Mootools is the following:

http://www.k1der.net/modules/blogs/public/country/demo/brooser.html

Do you know any similar plugins using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Try [PHP File Tree with JQuery](http://abeautifulsite.net/2007/06/php-file-tree/)

Comment: Also broken, it's here now: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery File Select](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/FileSelect)

The File Select plugin searches a directory for files and lists them. Once a file is selected, it's information is returned the the file is 'selected'.

haven't tried it but worth a look i guess